# Forge/BIM360: Is there still no way to get at BIM360 Docs custom attributes on files?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

I'm trying to read the custom attributes, which are defined at the folder level in BIM360 and then applied to individual file versions.

But I can't find any endpoint that seems to expose them.

Is it still not possible to read/write them?
(I see an Autodesk forum post from April that seems to say no, but I was hoping that they would be visible via the Forge APIs by now?).

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the information of folder/file is provided by Forge Data Management API, this API is used as a common access to many different Autodesk SAAS app like A360 Personal, BIM 360 Team, Fusion Team (formerly known as A360 Team), BIM 360 Docs.

Unfortunately, since the custom attributes are specified only for BIM360 Docs(correct me if I am wrong), so the Folder/Item API of Forge Date Management does not provide that information yet.